# Eliminate pixels on land on QGIS

Tags: raster, qgis-3, masking

I have black pixels inside water and land. I have covered the land using a shapefile. How do I mask out the entire land so that no pixel is counted on the land? I only want to count pixels inside the water.

Comment: Does Clip raster by mask layer help? If not, please be more precise and revise your question - probably add a screenshot so that it becomes clearer what you want to do. See:
https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rasterextraction.html?highlight=clip%20raster%20mask%20layer#clip-raster-by-mask-layer

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.